# Setting styles in Qt QLabels via style sheets and HTML classes

Tags: css, qt, pyqt

I have a QLabel in my Python/Qt 4.8 GUI, which contains a table. I'd like to style elements of this table with different colours. I realise I can use `<font>` tags but it seems a little more elegant to use classes and CSS. I want it to look like this:

[image: what I want it to look like]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table width=100%>
        <tr class="spec"><td>Wavelength:</td><td>{0:.2f} µm</td></tr>
        <tr class="spec"><td>Bandwidth:</td><td>{1:.2f} µm</td></tr>
        <tr class="oldPM"><td>Power:</td><td>{2:.1f} mW</td></tr>
        <tr class="newPM"><td>{3:.0f} sec stability:</td><td>{4:.1%} rms</td></tr>
        <tr class="newPM"><td></td><td>{5:.1%} p2p</tr>
</table>
```

And my CSS like this:

```
#oldPM {color: #333333}
#spec {color: blue}
#newPM {color: #333333}
```

But Qt doesn't seem to recognise the class selectors. Is this a fundamental limitation of the Qt styling, or am I doing something wrong? I can get it to change the style of the whole QLabel, using `QLabel` as a selector, but I want different parts of it to be styled differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QWidget::setStyleSheet` is used to apply Qt Style Sheets (QSS) to a widget. It does not support styling of widget rich text contents using CSS.

You can add your CSS to `QLabel` contents inside `<style>` tag as Qt supports it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html

Also note that `#spec` selector will be applied to an element with `id="spec"`. To select elements with `class="spec"` class you should use this syntax: `.spec`

So the full text of your QLabel should be:

```
<style>
    .oldPM {color: #333333}
    .spec {color: blue}
    .newPM {color: #333333}
</style>
<table width=100%>
    <tr class="spec"><td>Wavelength:</td><td>{0:.2f} µm</td></tr>
    <tr class="spec"><td>Bandwidth:</td><td>{1:.2f} µm</td></tr>
    <tr class="oldPM"><td>Power:</td><td>{2:.1f} mW</td></tr>
    <tr class="newPM"><td>{3:.0f} sec stability:</td><td>{4:.1%} rms</td></tr>
    <tr class="newPM"><td></td><td>{5:.1%} p2p</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Aha! I see. Thanks a lot. I knew it should be `.spec` - I'd been experimenting, and accidentally pasted the wrong version.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Although somehow it does only accept some CSS-properties, like font-formatting. But if I set `table {border: 1px solid #000000;}` it has no effect, even though the border-tag is explicitly mentioned in Qt's [html-subset](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).
Any idea why?